# Heap size in Netbeans java

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

My heapsize is too low and I tried to chang it. I did whatever told in here about stack overflew problem but the problem is always ones! It say I can not access to these file.
Netbeans configuration file does not run in adminestrator mode and when I open it with netbeans, an arorr shows me that I could not chang this file.
So what's the soloution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it in safe mode once. that will be okay